# WAMP doesn't load jQuery

Tags: jquery, wamp

I put my entire HTML project along with the .js files in `wamp/www/project/`  but when I go to `localhost/project`  it doesn't load any jQuery. When I go to  `file:///D:/wamp/www/project`  it is loaded perfectly.

Any solution?

Yes, WAMP works (I tried installing Joomla, and it worked like a charm)
No, skype is not turned on

Comment: Did you load the JS in your html files? (<script src="path/to/.js"></script>) and if so, did you use correct paths?

Comment: use net tab in a browser console to validate if paths  to resources are correct and check for script errors

Comment: Yes, the paths are good; these are the errors i have:

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined; 

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined; 

ReferenceError: $ is not defined;

Comment: if the path wasn't good or if there were script errors, it wouldn't work when i go to file:///D:/wamp/www/project ; right?

Answer (score 0):

Alot of the time when this happens it's because you've got some PHP code somewhere on your page thats generating errors and stopping javascript from running correctly, hence why it isn't an issue when you're viewing files on you're local machine. Check the errors console and http requests in firebug to get a better idea of whats going on.

EDIT: jQuery undefined means you're calling jQuery somewhere where the jQuery library isn't correctly loaded. This will most likely be one of two things, either A: You're using the $ symbol in an area where it's conflicting with PHP (change all '$'s in your jQuery to jQuery). or B: You're trying to call jQuery before the library has been loaded. Make sure you're not trying to run any plugins or have any of your scripts running before the jQuery library in the document.

Comment: I get reference error: $ not defined, and reference error: jQuery not defined

Answer (score 0):

It could be because some pieces of the jQuery code are interpreted as PHP if your server is programmed to look for PHP code in all types of files.

Try loading the jQuery file directly and look at the source or load it from the Google hosted url.

Check your PHP error logs.

Comment: When I loaded jQuery from google, my custom jquery showed, but the NivoSlider still doesn't work